# Unable to receive values sent through post method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to send ID and sent from ajax_form.php to ajax_test.php()

my ajax_form.php is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;
        var xmlhttp;
        var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
        //var sent = document.getElementsByName('sent')[0].value || '';
        //var id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value || '';
        var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
    var id = form.elements['id'].value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&id=' + id + '&' + submit.name + '=' + submit.value);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <label>Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit"  />
        <input type="" name="id" style="display: none"/>
    </form>

    <h4>UPDATE</h4>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
            <label>Enter the ID:</label><input type="text" name="id"><br>
                <label>Enter the sentence:<input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        </pre>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update"/>
    </form>

    <br />
    <div id="txtHint">
        <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax_test.php is:

```
    <html><head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    </head> <body > 
    <?php
    $s = $_POST['sent'];
    echo "Entered sentence : $s";

    if (isset($_POST['insert']) && $_POST['insert'] !== '') {
    echo "Operation: Insert","<br>";
    $s = $_POST['sent'];
    $flag = 0;
    echo "Entered sentence : $s";
    //database stuff

    mysqli_close($con);
    }

    // -------------------------------UPDATE --------------------------
     if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] !== '') {
    echo "Operation: update", "<br>";
     // you say update but you are actually inserting below

    $s    = $_POST['sent'];
    $flag = 1;

    echo "Entered sentence : $s";
//database stuff

         mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?></html > </body >
```

Neither content outside `if()` get executed correctly nor `if`
I get error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: sent in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/ajax_test.php on line 6
```

Just     `Entered sentence :`  get printed.

Where is the problem in post? Ideally I should able fetch `id` and `sent` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` on the request before sending it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I read the document. `$headers[] = 'Accept: application/ajax';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/ajax';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` ? But is this the problem behind issue?

Comment: _Before_ the line `xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);`, try adding `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was making tons of changes for last two days for this problem! Wish I could have given 10+ up votes!